# Add class to parent of <img> with certain class name or certain source

Tags: selector, yui, addclass, yui3

My HTML looks like this, and I'm working with the YUI library:

```
<div>
    <img class="smallimage" src="host/smallimage.jpg">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="host/bigimage.jpg">
</div>
```

I would like to know how to 
(1) add a class to the container  off all images with the class of .smallimage as well as 
(2) add a class to the container  of all images with the string 'big' in the source tag. :)

So that the output is like this:

```
<div class = "small">
    <img class="smallimage" src="host/smallimage.jpg">
</div>
<div class = "big">
    <img src="host/bigimage.jpg">
</div>
```

Thanks very much fellas!

**UPDATE:**
Fellas I think I have figured this out now, but would still apprecate if someone could maybe just look if its solid:

1)

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y)    
 var node = Y.one(".smallimage")
 Y.one(".smallimage").get('parentNode').addClass("small");
});
```

2)

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y)    
 var node = Y.one("img[src*='big']")
 Y.one("img[src*='big']").get('parentNode').addClass("big");
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but as the function says using `Y.one` will affect only one element. If you have multiple images you should use `Y.all`.

Also, keep in mind that you can do everything inside one `YUI().use()` call.